# When I put Frame2 onto Frame1 the components of Frame2 appear behind the components of Frame1 until I hover them

Tags: user-interface, delphi, interface, components, frame

Basically im trying to get a Pause screen for my Tetris Game with the Gameframe frozen in the background. Problem is that once I put my PauseFrame onto the GameFrame my PauseFrame components are behind my TPanels.

[image]

Theres 2 more buttons under the "Weiter" Button which are not showing because i didnt hover them

This is how I show the PauseFrame:

```
procedure TTetrisFrame.PauseGame(Sender: TObject);
var
  myMenuFrame: TFrame;
begin
     PauseBtn.Visible := false;
     EinGameMaster.Pause;
     myMenuFrame := TPauseFrame.Create(Nil);
     myMenuFrame.Parent := Self;
end;
```

This is the Pauseframe:

[image: This is the Pauseframe]

Pauseframe Code:

```
type
  TPauseFrame = class(TFrame)
    BackgroundImg: TImage;
    WeiterBtn: TButton;
    NeustartenBtn: TButton;
    HauptmenueBtn: TButton;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);override;
    procedure PaintWindow(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
  end;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
    GameFrame, Main;

constructor TPauseFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
     inherited;
     BringToFront;
     HauptmenueBtn.BringToFront;
     Brush.Style := bsClear;
end;

procedure TPauseFrame.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
end;

procedure TPauseFrame.PaintWindow(DC: HDC);
begin
  // Comment for transparency
end;

end.
```

GameFrame Code:

```
type
  TTetrisFrame = class(TFrame)
  private
    procedure PlacePauseButton;
    procedure DrawPlayingfield;
    procedure DrawOberflaeche;
  public
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;


implementation


{$R *.dfm}

uses
    UPauseFrame;
var
    TetrisPlayfield: array of array of TPanel;
    PauseBtn: TButton;

{ TFrame1 }

constructor TTetrisFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
     inherited;
     Left := 5;
     Top := 25;
     DrawPlayingfield;
end;

procedure TTetrisFrame.DrawPlayingfield;
var
   index,index2: integer;
const
     LeftPosition = 150;
     TopPosition = 600;
begin
     SetLength(9,19);
     for index := 0 to 9 do begin
        for index2 := 0 to 19 do begin
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2] := TPanel.Create(Nil);
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].Parent := Self;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].ParentBackground := false;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].ParentColor := false;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].BevelInner := bvNone;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].BevelOuter := bvLowered;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].BevelKind := bkNone;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].Height := 30;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].width := 30;
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].Left := LeftPosition + (index * 30);
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].Top := TopPosition - (index2 * 30);
           TetrisPlayfield[index,index2].Visible := True;
        end;
     end;
end;

procedure TTetrisFrame.PauseGame(Sender: TObject);
var
  myMenuFrame: TFrame;
begin
     EinGameMaster.Pause;
     PauseBtn.Visible := false;
     myMenuFrame := TPauseFrame.Create(Nil);
     myMenuFrame.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure TTetrisFrame.PlacePauseButton;
begin
     PauseBtn := TButton.Create(Nil);
     PauseBtn.Parent := Self;
     PauseBtn.Width := 100;
     PauseBtn.Height := 60;
     PauseBtn.Left := 50;
     PauseBtn.Top := 500;
     PauseBtn.Caption := 'Pause';
     PauseBtn.OnClick := PauseGame;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please show the Frame2 definition and how you are showing it.

Comment: Edited the Post :)

Comment: Well, I asked for the Frame2 definition, iow class. But actually, why are you even using a frame, since a modal form would be a better choice?

Comment: I have been given the task to use Frames. Basically just a learning measurement :D And sorry, I misread that. I will add the definition right away

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem you have. Please provide a [mre]. The purpose is to be able to reproduce the problem with simply copying the code you provide into the IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure that disabling PaintWindow() is a good idea. Did you check if it's the cause of the issue?

Comment: @Olivier Just tested it and its not the cause of the issue. I disabled PaintWindow to get transparency though, if I re-enable it it acts weird and deleted some of my panels.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Just added example code. :)

Comment: An old rule I have followed is that WS_EX_COMPOSITED is meant for top level windows only, but I'm not sure if that is a fact. Anyway, removing it solves the problem. Alternatively you can omit `CreateParams()` for the frame, and simply set the properties `ParentBackground` and `ParentColor` both false, since you are setting `Brush.Style := bsClear;`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!